# How to eliminate the glitch in scale3D?

Tags: css, animation

I have problems scale3D. So, when These animations move. There is a glitch in the animation. or like flash. What can be eliminated? Is this because the browser problem? or indeed like this?

This my code:

```css
.sk-cube-grid {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube {
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
  background-color: #333;
  float: left;
  -webkit-animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 2.3s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;}
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube6 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube7 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;}
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube8 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube9 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; }

@-webkit-keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
  0%, 70%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
            transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
  } 35% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
            transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sk-cube-grid">
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube1"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube2"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube3"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube4"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube5"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube6"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube7"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube8"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks great in Chrome for macOS. Need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has entirely to do with your easing function.

Couple notes:

1. You don't need `scale3D` here.  There's no `z` axis scaling happening.
2. Be aware that any *curved* easing applied to an element that reaches `0` runs the risk of heading into negative territory.

With that said, using a `linear` easing eliminates the problem.  I'd suggest looking at a cubic-bezier function if you want to curve the animation timing.

```css
.sk-cube-grid {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube {
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
  background-color: #333;
  float: left;
  -webkit-animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 2.3s infinite linear;
}
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;}
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube6 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube7 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;}
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube8 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube9 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; }

@-webkit-keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
  0%, 70%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
            transform: scale(1, 1);
  } 35% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
            transform: scale(0, 0); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sk-cube-grid">
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube1"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube2"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube3"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube4"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube5"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube6"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube7"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube8"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube9"></div>
</div>
```